# thmtools -> cite paper in head of theorem

Tags: thmtools

I'ld like to do get an alternative of the following code, working with thmtools:

```
\begin{theorem}[Theorem X.X of \cite{foo}] bar \end{theorem}
```

When I do the following:

```
\begin{theorem}[name={Theorem X.X of \cite{foo}}] bar \end{theorem}
```

if theorem is an environment created in my header using

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,    name=Theorem,       numberwithin=section]{theorem}
```

I'm getting errors. Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I managed to isolate the issue. It is related with some modifications of the cite command by the ijcai17 package (which I am obliged to use).

So: minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ijcai17}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=plain, name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}[name={Theorem X.X of \cite{icdt/Abiteboul88}}] 
bar
\end{theorem}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Abiteboul, 1988]{icdt/Abiteboul88}
Abiteboul, S. (1988).
\newblock Updates, a new frontier.
\newblock pages 1--18.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

using the ijcai17.sty from http://ijcai-17.org/FormattingGuidelinesIJCAI-17.zip

Comment: Maybe try `\protect\cite`? If this does not help, can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Citing inside theorem header](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/citing-inside-theorem-header)

Comment: Related: [`thmtools`: how to put xrefs in argument to `thm` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29372/5764)

Comment: @samcarter This is a completely different problem than in the question you linked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by samcarter, using `\protect` does the trick.

Here is my minimal example updated, giving me the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ijcai17}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=plain, name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}[name={Theorem X.X of \protect\cite{icdt/Abiteboul88}}] 
bar
\end{theorem}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Abiteboul, 1988]{icdt/Abiteboul88}
Abiteboul, S. (1988).
\newblock Updates, a new frontier.
\newblock pages 1--18.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

still
using the ijcai17.sty from http://ijcai-17.org/FormattingGuidelinesIJCAI-17.zip

Answer (score 2):

The package you are forced to use file makes a few basic errors, that can be readily fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ijcai17}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[style=plain, name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}

% fix the stupid mistakes in ijcai17
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cite{%
  \def\citeauthoryear##1##2{\def\@thisauthor{##1}%
  \ifx \@lastauthor \@thisauthor \relax \else##1, \fi ##2}%        
  \@icite 
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\shortcite{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@icite}
\DeclareRobustCommand\citeauthor{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##1}\@nbcite}
\DeclareRobustCommand\citeyear{\def\citeauthoryear##1##2{##2}\@nbcite}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Theorem X.X of \cite{icdt/Abiteboul88}]
bar
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Abiteboul, 1988]{icdt/Abiteboul88}
Abiteboul, S. (1988).
\newblock Updates, a new frontier.
\newblock pages 1--18.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note that

```
\begin{theorem}[name=Theorem X.X of \cite{icdt/Abiteboul88}]
```

would work in the same way; I see no need for using the `key-value` syntax.

### Original answer, due to the OP not really showing the problem

It will be at least confusing, I'm afraid. Anyway, you can't use the `name` key in the optional argument to `theorem`: it's a key for `\declaretheorem` only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=\protect\namedtheoremname,
  numberwithin=section
]{namedtheoreminner}
\newcommand{\namedtheoremname}{}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand\namedtheoremname{#1}%
  \namedtheoreminner}
 {\endnamedtheoreminner}

\begin{document}

\section{A theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}{Theorem X.X of \cite{foo}}
Some theorem in another paper
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{foo} Foo

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use name in the theorem environment. See page 8 of http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf

Comment: @BartBog Yes, but not with the result you ask for. Anyway, I get no error.

Comment: Well, it is with the result I want at least. 

The result can look like <b>Theorem X (Theorem X.X of Y)</b>

Comment: There is no error, in that case. Maybe you have `\cite[p. 13]{foo}`? Please, add a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: I updated with a minimal failing example

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. Could you elaborate on what is wrong with the ijcai file? (the same mistakes should be in the named.sty file) And on how to fix it?

Comment: No, `named.bst` should not be a problem. If you look at the `ijcai17.sty` file, you see that they have an example with `\documentstyle`; instead of making a good style file for today's LaTeX, they just modified slightly a LaTeX2.09 style file: a guarantee for problems.